# Is it possible to connect to 3rd party database using Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Cloud and looking to cut down cost on Azure. I already have a database on the hostinger platform and would like to use it for the python script that I want to run on the Azure Logic Apps platform. Is it possible to do this or does Azure prevent any such connections? Do I need to create any connector on Azure for this purpose? I have no idea of running python script on Azure. If this is possible then it can be a great cost cutting measure for me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the workarounds is you can try using Remote MySQL from the Databases of the Hostinger platform.

Type the IP address of your remote server in the IP (IPv4 or IPv6) area on the Remote MySQL page, or check the Any Host box to connect from any IP.

[image]

Then choose the database you wish to access from afar. Click Create when you're finished.

[image]

Make sure that a MySQL user must use their MySQL server hostname for remote connections - the hostname may be found at the top of the same page.

[image]

You may now use the same connection to make your own logic app connector and utilize the same connector for additional database manipulations.

> would like to use it for the python script that I want to run on the Azure Logic Apps platform.

Depending on your requirements, you may utilize a variety of connectors for this. For example following the custom connector that you are using to retrieve the database from your hostinger, you can use azure functions in order to while coding with python.

For more information, you can refer to this [example](https://github.com/tinhthanh/AzureRemoteMsql).

**REFERENCES:**
[How to Allow Remote Connections to MySQL Database (hostinger.in)](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/mysql/how-to-grant-remote-access-mysql-vps#:%7E:text=If%20you%20use%20Hostinger%2C%20you%20can%20connect%20to,hPanel%20and%20navigate%20to%20Databases%20-%3E%20Remote%20MySQL.)

Comment: Thankyou for your response! Creating a connector is additional efforts which I might not want to take. If my python code is already connecting to the hostinger remote MySQL and I put this app on the Azure logic apps platform, then still we need the connector to be created?